# Automatic migration from Datastore to Firestore - Region Change

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

It's been a little while since we were warned of the migration from the Datastore to Firestore (in Datastore mode).

When we first created our app we didn't have access to regions (early adopters) - and I was hoping we would have the opportunity to change the region of the app when the migration happens. Does anyone know if we can choose the region of the servers before the migration begins? Or should we just bite the bullet and migrate manually?

Thanks in advance,

Guy

Comment: Yes thank you! So sorry I was slow on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of your Firestore should be the same as your Project's location.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/locations#selecting_a_location) says the following:

> The location setting for your Google Cloud project applies to both
> Firestore in Datastore mode and App Engine. When you select a location
> in either product, you set the location for your entire Google Cloud
> project.

> Important: After you select the location of your project, you cannot change it.

You can [verify your project's location](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/locations#viewing_the_location_of_your_project) by running  `gcloud app describe`.

If you can't see your project's location because your app is used since the time there was no access to regions, I'd double-check that with the [GCP Support](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getting-support).

Answer (score 1):

The migration to Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode will not change the location of your database.

As of today (2021-06-07) if you want to change the location of your Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database, you'll need to do so manually.